# SQL not receiving any data from php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file with a form that gets the data after the user submits, everything okay until i insert the data to sql, for some reason i don't get any kind of sql or php error but when i check for the data on the database, and on the if that i have to check if it worked or not it always goes for "work", is there any clues of what i'm doing wrong?

```php
<?php
//conecta-se ao servidor de MySql e à base de dados 'lojadb':
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rgbon");

//verifica a conexão:
if(!$conn){
    die("Erro na conexão à base de dados");
}

$error = NULL;


if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  //get form data
  $username = $_POST["username"];
  $email = $_POST["email"];
  $p1 = $_POST["p1"];
  $p2 = $_POST["p2"];


  if(strlen($username) < 5) {
    $error = "<p>Your username must be at least 5 characters</p>";
  }elseif($p2 != $p1) {
    $error .= "<p> Your passwords do not match!</p>";
  }else{
    //form is valid

    //sanitize form data
    $username = $conn->real_escape_string($username);
    $email = $conn->real_escape_string($email);
    $p1 = $conn->real_escape_string($p1);
    $p2 = $conn->real_escape_string($p2);

    //generate vkey
    $vkey = md5(time() . $username);

    //Insert account into the database
    $p1 = md5($p1);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO utilizador (Username, Password, Email, vkey)
    VALUES('$username', '$p1', '$email', '$vkey')";
    if($insert) {
       echo "<h1> work</h1>";


    }else{
      echo "<h1> dont work</h1>";
      echo $conn->error;
    }
```

Comment: You build the query text in `$insert` but do not execute it...

Comment: Never use MD5 for passwords, you can properly hash passwords since PHP 5.5. See [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) and [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

at this line

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO utilizador (Username, Password, Email, vkey)
VALUES('$username', '$p1', '$email', '$vkey')"
```

You set the insert code at a variable named `$insert`, But you did not use it!
so, you should execute the query by

```
$result = $conn-> query($insert);
```

thin check it working

```
if($result) {
   echo "<h1> work</h1>";
```

by replacing `$insert` variable to `$result`

Comment: damn im so dumb i had username has an integer on the database that's why it was working i only saw the error after doing what you said, thank you very much :p

Comment: No problem bro, we often make such mistakes, have a nice day :D